# Why is curl is throwing exception with error 35

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting uncaught exceptions for curl.

Thought in update curl but I don't really know how to do it.
Using Google Cloud Platform running PHP in a flex environment.

```
exception:  "Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: cURL error 35: gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php:263
Stack trace:
#0 /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php(168): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->convertToGoogleException(Object(GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException))
#1 /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RestTrait.php(95): Google\Cloud\Core\RequestWrapper->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array)
#2 /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-logging/src/Connection/Rest.php(60): Google\Cloud\Logging\Connection\Rest->send('entries', 'write', Array)
#3 /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-logging/src/Logger.php(389): Google\Cloud\Logging\Connection\Rest->writeEntries(Array)
#4 /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-logging/src/Logger.php(358): Google\Cloud\Logging\Logger->writeBatch(Array, Array)
#5 /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-logging/src/PsrLogger.php(528): Google\Cloud\Logging\Logger->write(Object(Google\Cloud\Logging\Entry))
#6 /app/symfony/vendor/google/cloud-logging/src/PsrLogger.php(413): Google\Cloud\Logging\PsrLogger->sendEntry(Object(Google\Cloud\Logging\Entry))
#7 /app/symfony/src/Services/StackDriverHandler.php(58): Google\Cloud\Logging\PsrLogger->log('critical', 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)
#8 /app/symfony/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): App\Services\StackDriverHandler->handle(Array)
#9 /app/symfony/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(644): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(500, 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)
#10 /app/symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php(108): Monolog\Logger->critical('Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)
#11 /app/symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php(48): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener->logException(Object(Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException), 'Uncaught PHP Ex...')
#12 /app/symfony/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(212): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener->logKernelException(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent), 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher))
#13 /app/symfony/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))
#14 /app/symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(219): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.exceptio...', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent))
#15 /app/symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(77): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleException(Object(Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException), Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#16 /app/symfony/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(188): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#17 /app/symfony/public/index.php(34): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#18 {main}"
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Most likely you do not have certificates installed. Review the article: https://www.jhanley.com/curl-ssl-certificate-problem/

Comment: This is not related to my code base but to Google Cloud Platform flex environment. The problem is that I don't really know how to update SSL certificate using a flex environment. Maybe is not possible at all.